# How can I implement a progress animation inside a imageView?

Tags: android, eclipse

I am loading some images in a listView using the url from the rss feed. But the load a bit late in the EDGE connection, Can I use a small progess dialog during the loading of the images?

Answer (score 1):

you can use this code for that

animation file

[image: XML CODE]

......

....

```
final AnimationDrawable frameAnimation = (AnimationDrawable) getResources().getDrawable(R.anim.animation_loding);

        imageView.setImageDrawable(frameAnimation);


        Timer timer = new Timer();
         timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
          @Override
          public void run() {
           frameAnimation.start();
          }
         }, 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using an AsyncTask to get the data from your RSS feed, you can place a ProgressDialog in your PreExecute (init) and PostExecute (dismiss). That would overlay your activity.

I am not sure the best way to use a progress animation inside the ImageView itself.

Comment: No he is talking about to place Progress animation for imageview of each item.

Comment: I've already use a Async Task for initial loading for all the images and text news from rss, but after that I've use a method downloadBitmap which will first load the images, then cache it on the device, for using a low end EDGE connection the images comes later and the text comes first in the listView.

Answer (score 0):

I had the very same problem. I implemented a ASyncImageView which extends ImageView. Every ASyncImageView has an ASyncTask running and getting the image for it in the background while the list is already loaded. This way the images will get there on their own and the listview is still there.

Comment: I've already use a Async Task for initial loading for all the images and text news from rss, but after that I've use a method downloadBitmap which will first load the images, then cache it on the device, for using a low end EDGE connection the images comes later and the text comes first in the listView.